# trigger Playa’s update script

Tags: playa

I updated from 4.3 to 4.4, I followed the update guide, and in the step "Go to Add-Ons → Fieldtypes → Playa to trigger Playa’s update script."

I do not see any button to do that, of it is done automatically?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the Add-Ons → Fieldtypes → Playa page and the update script will automatically run in the background.